# typescript debugging in visual studio angular 2 application

Tags: typescript, angular, visual-studio-debugging, systemjs

I can't get TS debugging to work in visual studio 2015 with angular 2 application.  Here is my index / _layout file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<base href="/" />
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/lib/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/lib/primeui-ng-all.min.css" />

<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
@*@Scripts.Render("~/startup");*@
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="~/Scripts/lib/breeze-client/breeze.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/lib/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/lib/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/lib/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/lib/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/lib/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/lib/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
    System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,

        meta: {
            '*.js': { scriptLoad: true } //this allows TS debugging in VS
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },

        },
        map: {
            'rxjs': 'scripts/lib/rxjs',
            'angular2': 'scripts/lib/angular2',
            'primeng': 'scripts/lib/primeng'
        }
    });
    System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>





</head>
<body>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>



@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

here is my tsconfig

```
{
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "system",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false
},
"exclude": [
"node_modules",
"typings/main",
"typings/main.d.ts",
"typings/browser.d.ts"
]
}
```

if I comment out the "meta" config everything work correctly and the application loads / runs as expected.

if I put the meta code in, I get the following errors

http://localhost:32532/scripts/lib/angular2/core.js did not call System.register or AMD define. If loading a global module configure the global name via the meta exports property for script injection support

I'm also using ts 1.8.9

Comment: Is the "node_modules" folder part of your VIsual Studio project? The compiler should not be looking down that folder. Make sure it is excluded from your project.

Comment: I just looked at your path again - are your angular libraries in the node_modules folder or in scripts?